# Only Half of the new Jpanel is showing after logging in

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I have a log in system and it logs in fine but it only shows half of the new jPanel when the user signs in
I am using Java and Netbeans

This is my code:

```
 if(loggedIn){
                Main_Menu panel= new Main_Menu();
                controlPanel.setVisible(false);
                mainFrame.remove(controlPanel);
                mainFrame.add(controlPanel2);
                controlPanel2.add(panel);  
                controlPanel2.setVisible(true);
            }
        }catch(SQLException ex){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Problem executing SQL Query.");
```

The old panel is removed and the new panel is added but when you log in only half of the jPanel is visible, why would this be?

Answer (score 0):

> only half of the jPanel is visible, why would this be?

The size of the second panel is larger so you need to pack() the frame so all components are displayed at their preferred size.

Or another option is to use a `Card Layout` and let the layout manager handle the swapping of panels. It will also manage the size properly.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for more information and working examples.